# How to properly set the CABasicAnimation (begin) time?

Tags: ios, delay, cabasicanimation

I animate the color of `CAShapeLayers` stored in an Array using CABasicAnimation. The animation displays erratically depending on the `animation.duration` and I cannot figure out why. I suspect an issue with `animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + delay`

**Animation Description**

The animation consists in successively flashing shapes to yellow before turning them to black once the animation ends.

**Current State of the animation**

When the animation duration is above a certain time, it works properly.

- *For instance with a duration of 2 seconds:*

[image: 2-second animation]

But when I shorten the duration, the result substantially differs.

- *For instance, with a duration of 1 second:*

[image: 1-second animation:]

You will notice that the animation has already cached/ended for the first 10 bars or so, then waits and starts animating the remainder of the shapes.

- *Likewise, with a duration of 0.5s:*

[image: 0.5s animation]

In this case, it seems an even larger number of animation has already ended (shapes are black) before it displays some animation after a certain time. You can also notice that although the shape color animation is supposed to last the same duration (0.5s) some feels quicker than others.

**The Code**

*The animation is called in the viewDidAppear method of the UIViewController class.*

I have created a UIView custom class to draw my shapes and I animate them using an extension of the class.

The code to animate the color:

```
    enum ColorAnimation{
        case continuousSwap
        case continousWithNewColor(color: UIColor)
        case randomSwap
        case randomWithNewColor(color: UIColor)
        case randomFromUsedColors
    }


    func animateColors(for duration: Double,_ animationType: ColorAnimation, colorChangeDuration swapColorDuration: Double){
        guard abs(swapColorDuration) != Double.infinity else {
            print("Error in defining the shape color change duration")
            return
        }
        let animDuration = abs(duration)
        let swapDuration = abs(swapColorDuration)
        let numberOfSwaps = Int(animDuration / min(swapDuration, animDuration))


        switch animationType {
        case .continousWithNewColor(color: let value):
            var fullAnimation = [CABasicAnimation]()
            for i in (0...numberOfSwaps) {
                let index = i % (self.pLayers.count)
                let fromValue = pLayers[index].pattern.color
                let delay =  Double(i) * swapDuration / 3
                let anim = colorAnimation(for: swapDuration, fromColor: value, toColor: fromValue, startAfter: delay)
                fullAnimation.append(anim)
            }

            for i in (0...numberOfSwaps) {
                CATransaction.begin()
                 let index = i % (self.pLayers.count)
                CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
                    self.pLayers[index].shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                }
                pLayers[index].shapeLayer.add(fullAnimation[i], forKey: "fillColorShape")
                CATransaction.commit()
            }
        default:
            ()
        }
    }
```

The segment the whole duration of the animation by the duration of the color change (*e.g.* if the whole animation is 10s and each shape changes color in 1s, it means 10 shapes will change color).
I then create the CABasicaAnimation objects using the method colorAnimation(for: fromColor, toColor, startAfter:).

```
func colorAnimation(for duration: TimeInterval, fromColor: UIColor, toColor: UIColor, reverse: Bool = false, startAfter delay: TimeInterval) -> CABasicAnimation {
        let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "fillColor")
        anim.fromValue = fromColor.cgColor
        anim.toValue = toColor.cgColor
        anim.duration = duration
        anim.autoreverses = reverse
        anim.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + delay
        return anim
    }
```

Finally I add the animation to the adequate CAShapeLayer.
The code can obviously be optimized but I chose to proceed by these steps to try to find why it was not working properly.

**Attempts so far**

So far, I have tried:

- with and without setting the `animation.beginTime` in the colorAnimation method, including with and without `CACurrentMediaTime()`: if I don't set the `animation.beginTime` with `CACurrentMediaTime`, I simply do not see any animation.
- with and without pointing `animation.delegate = self`: it did not change anything.
- using DispatchQueue (store the animations in global and run it in main) and as suspected, the shapes did not animate.

I suspect something is not working properly with the beginTime but it might not be the case, or only this because even when the shapes animate, the shape animation duration seems to vary whilst it should not.

Thank very much in advance to have a look to this issue. Any thoughts are welcome even if it seems far-fetched it can open to new ways to address this!

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a relationship between duration and swapColorDuration

`func animateColors(for duration: Double,_ animationType: ColorAnimation, colorChangeDuration swapColorDuration: Double)`

when you call it, you may need to keep this relationship

```
    let colorChangeDuration: TimeInterval = 0.5
    animateColors(for: colorChangeDuration * TimeInterval(pLayers.count), .continousWithNewColor(color: UIColor.black), colorChangeDuration: colorChangeDuration)
```

Also here :

```
 let numberOfSwaps = Int(animDuration / min(swapDuration, animDuration)) - 1
```

This value maybe a little higher than you need.

or

The problem lies in this `let index = i % (self.pLayers.count)`

`if  numberOfSwaps >  self.pLayers.count`, some bands will be double animations.

```
 let numberOfSwaps1 = Int(animDuration / min(swapDuration, animDuration))
 let numberOfSwaps = min(numberOfSwaps1, self.pLayers.count)
```

in the rest is

```
       for i in (0..<numberOfSwaps) {... }
```

Now if  `numberOfSwaps <  self.pLayers.count`. It's not finished.

if numberOfSwaps is larger, It is fine.

If double animations are required, changes the following:

`pLayers[index].shapeLayer.add(fullAnimation[i], forKey: nil)`

or `pLayers[index].shapeLayer.add(fullAnimation[i], forKey: "fillColorShape" + String(i))`

Comment: Thanks for having had a look! In fact `duration` is the time of the full animation whilst  `swapDuration` is the duration of the actual color change. The relation between them is explained in the question: you run x times the color change animation, x being the **Integer resulting from duration / swapDuration**. In all examples I put in GIF the `duration` was set to 40s, and `swapDuration` was set respectively to 2s, 1s, 0.5s. Thus I don't really see why this relationship could explain the animation behaviour.

Comment: The last line will solve the last minute band problem. Maybe the value is larger than necessary.  The relationship here is if swapDuration is small and  numberOfSwaps will be bigger than the count of shapeLayer. so  there is more time to wait  before the animation actual happened.

Comment: I have played a bit around your idea and it does have an impact. I have indeed realised that if the ratio `duration / swapDuration` is inferior at `pLayers.count`, the animation shows properly. I am digging in... and will report back! Thanks!

Comment: I see what you did, thanks! But the thing is: I want some bands to double the animation if the duration of the animation is larger than the addition of all the bands animation...

Comment: If double animations, their key should be different. `pLayers[index].shapeLayer.add(fullAnimation[i], forKey: "fillColorShape")`

Comment: you can use `pLayers[index].shapeLayer.add(fullAnimation[i], forKey: nil)`

Comment: That did the trick! In fact I just need to change `pLayers[index].shapeLayer.add(fullAnimation[i], forKey: "fillColorShape")` to something like `pLayers[index].shapeLayer.add(fullAnimation[i], forKey: "fillColorShape" + String(i))` and voilà! And I finally understood the underlying issue. Thanks a lot!!! You might want to update your answer so I can accept it and you get your rep up :)

Comment: I did. Thanks you.